# The layer of DTO conversions

Tags: java, oop, model-view-controller, architecture

Controller should work with DTO, service with domain models. For communications between controller and service what is best place for conversion from DTO to models, in controller or service? And also, what is the best place for building DTO after executing service logic?

Comment: you can write separate MappingUtils which will map DTOs to models and models to DTOs

Answer (score 1):

The best place for conversion from DTO to Models and vice-versa is a Mapper.

You should not place the conversion logic in Service code, because a DTO can be used by multiple services. Placing it into Service code makes it tied to one specific service. Not a solution.

You should not place the conversion logic into a controller, because services, in order to convert something, become dependent on the controller. Not a solution.

Create a `Mapper` interface. Provide implementation for it (you can even use a library for mapping, like [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/)). And use this mapper for conversion whenever you need.

Comment: thanks for the answer
and mapper should be executed from controller, right?
and after getting the results from service, we need to prepare DTO again by mapper which is executed from controller, correct?